# Github workflow without .ENV

Tags: flutter, github-actions, flutter-dotenv

I'm trying to setup a Github Workflow pipeline for my Flutter App but `building` and `flutter analyze` commands fail since I do not commit my .ENV file

Is there a way to add the .ENV to my Workflow **without** committing it to source control ?

*Since `.env` shouldn’t be commited*

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - dev

jobs:
  flutter_test:
    name: Run flutter test and analyze
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter analyze
      - run: flutter test

  build_ios:
    name: Build Flutter (iOS)
    needs: [flutter_test]
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign

  build_appbundle:
    name: Build Flutter (Android)
    needs: [flutter_test]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: "12.x"
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter build appbundle
```

Comment: Have you checked your .gitignore?

Comment: What do you mean ? .env should not be checked into source control i’m looking for solution to use it’s values without having it checked

Comment: you can define them like this https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables and store the values in Action Secrets

Comment: @Sunshine did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you previously commit .env then add it to .gitignore after?

You can remove .env from git cache:

```
git rm --cached -r <path to your .env>
```